# How can I preserve the value of my parameters through a function so it can be used multiple times with its initial value?

Tags: python, sage

I have just started using SAGE which is pretty close to python as I understand it, and I have come accross this problem where I'll have as a parameter of a function a matrix which I wish to use multiple times in the function with its same original function but through the different parts of the function it changes values.

I have seen in a tutorial that declaring a variable in the function as
`variable = list(parameter)` doesnt affect the parameter or whatever is put in the parentheses. However I can't make it work..
Below is part of my program posing the problem (I can add the rest if necessary): I declare the variable `determinant` which has as value the result of the function `my_Gauss_determinant` with the variable `auxmmatrix` as parameter. Through the function `my_Gauss_determinant` the value of `auxmmatrix` changes but for some reason the value of `mmatrix` as well. How can avoid this and be able to re-use the parameter `mmatrix` with its original value?

```
def my_Cramer_solve(mmatrix,bb):
    auxmmatrix=list(mmatrix)
    determinant=my_Gauss_determinant(auxmmatrix)
    if determinant==0:
        print 
    k=len(auxmmatrix)
       solution=[]
        for l in range(k):
            auxmmatrix1=my_replace_column(list(mmatrix),l,bb)
            determinant1=my_Gauss_determinant(auxmmatrix1)
            solution.append(determinant1/determinant0)
    return  solution
```

Comment: What is the type of `mmatrix`?

Comment: It is a list for example aa=[[1,1],[0,2]]   and so is bb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a *copy* of `mmatrix`.  The reason `list(other_list)` works is because it iterates through every item in `other_list` to create a new list.  But the mutable objects `within` the list aren't copied

```
>>> a = [{1,2}]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> b[0].add(7)
>>> a
[set([1,2,7])]
```

To make a complete copy, you can use `copy.deepcopy` to make copies of the elements within the list

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = [{1,2}]
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b[0].add(7)
>>> a
[set([1,2])]
```

So if you only want to copy the list, but don't want to copy the *elements within the list*, you would do this

```
auxmmatrix = copy.copy(matrix)
determinant = my_Gauss_determinant(copy.copy(matrix))
```

If you want to copy the elements within the list as well, use `copy.deepcopy`

Comment: Thank you for the answer sadly this is for a homework and we are only aloud to use the most basic functions from SAGE, and I don't think I can use copy.deepcopy .

Comment: If it's just a list, you can do a shallow copy using slicing -- `auxmatrix = mmatrix[:]`

Comment: I still have the same problem if I do `print mmatrix` before and after `my_Gauss_determinant(auxmmatrix)`in the following code I have two different lists while I want to keep mmatrix the same
 `def my_Cramer_solve(mmatrix,bb):  auxmmatrix=list(mmatrix)  determinant=my_Gauss_determinant(auxmmatrix)`

Comment: You have to do another copy for the argument too -- `my_Gauss_determinant(auxmatrix[:])`, again, it's only doing a shallow copy, the lists within that list aren't being copied, if you're modifying them in the function, it's also going to affect `auxmatrix`

Comment: Your *really* should be using `copy.deepcopy`.  It's part of the standard library for python.  If you absolutely don't want to use it, you can do a psuedo-deep copy for a list of lists using  `newmatrix = [a[:] for a in matrix]`

Answer (score 0):

If `m` is a matrix, you can copy it into `mm` by doing

```
sage: mm = m[:, :]
```

or

```
sage: mm = matrix(m)
```

To understand the need to copy container structures such as lists and matrices, you could read [the tutorial on objects and classes in Python and Sage](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/tutorial-objects-and-classes.html).

The [other Sage tutorials](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/) are recommended too!